# Tree of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, tree

I'm looking for a "tree of checkboxes" widget for Javascript.  I tried to use [jquery-checktree](http://jquery-checktree.googlecode.com/) which purports to do exactly what I want, however it has the following problems:

- It doesn't recognize checkboxes that are already checked and renders everything as unchecked.
- It starts off with everything collapsed and doesn't give an option to start with everything uncollapsed
- Each line of my tree starts indented from the line above, even if they are `<li>` in the same `<ul>`.

Can anybody recommend one that works, or fixes for this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a few fixes to jquery-checktree and using it.  Some of the changes are probably broadly applicable and I emailed them to the developer, and others are probably only useful to my project.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [YUI TreeView](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/). They have an [example with checkboxes](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/treeview/tv_highlight.html). It might not be ideal for all uses, but it's pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

[ExtJS 3.x has one](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/check-tree.html).  I have not used it, but it looks nice.  Not sure if you're willing to add ExtJS to your stack...

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/) which is based on jquery also.