# YUI 3.5: tree of checkboxes

Tags: yui, yui3

I'd like to create a tree with checkboxes within YUI 3.5 like this:

```
|v|1
--| |1.1
--| |1.2
| |2
```

-- after 1.2 and 2 were checked;

```
|v|1
--| |1.1
--|v|1.2
-----| |1.2.1
|v|2
--| |2.1
```

`|v|` -- checked;
`| |` -- unchecked

Found yui3.5 docs a little bit strange because [that's](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-chkboxselect.html) all i've managed to found about checkboxes. 
 Nothing about single checkbox element nor about tree in YUI 3.5.

So, the question: where can i find some info about checkbox, checkbox's listener or checkbox-tree?

*P.S.* 
Sorry for my English and thanks in advance.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321203/tree-of-checkboxes) is not relevant as it references to yui2, extjs and jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was pretty easy.

`Y.Node.create("html-code-here");` -- to create a selectbox.

To build described tree: observe the checkboxes for changes to hide/show nearest children. 
My [*show* / *hide*] actions looked like toggling css styles for appropriate selectboxes:
 `display: block;` <-> `display: none;`

Though it's probably not the answer i would had been looking for i'll leave it as this was my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for almost same problem , i found following solution,

[Custom TreeView with Check Boxes](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/treeview/tasklist.html)

Comment: I saw that thing and found it not really customizable

Comment: so have you a better solution now?

Comment: @ted , i am thinking to use html tags for check boxes in label,  byself as u said :)

Comment: i've needed something like: generating tree on fly. To be able to generate correct tree structure using AJAX requests to get data for that tree. e.g. `data = getData(); generateTree(data);`